# How to reboot windows when RDP password equal some value

Tags: windows, rdp, reboot

How to reboot windows (automatically) when RDP password equal some value?

**For example :**

Password for `RDP == "hello_world"`. When user enter with this password Windows will work as usual. But if `password == 'bye_world'` Windows will reboot.

Comment: If you can make a `.bat` execute from this, i'd look up `http://www.computerhope.com/shutdown.htm`.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea

Comment: What's the context?  Are you talking about making this happen when a user logs in remotely via Remote Desktop, based on the password used to log in?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a batch file as @Da_smokes suggested

```
set /p password=Enter rdp password:
if "%password%"=="hello_world" mstsc /whatever you want to do
if "%password%"=="bye_world" shutdown /s /t 0 /f
```